# take number of rows delimited by a value

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the thing, i have a series which is like this:

```
 id
608    0
609    1
610    0
611    2
612    0
613    0
614    0
615    1
616    2
617    1
```

I want count how many values have before and after some point, for example:

> Before the first number 2 i have 3 rows and after i have 4 then i
> reach another number 2 which have 1 row after him.

So i want retrieve a list which will be like this:

```
[3, 4, 1]
```

Have some method to do this on pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `cumsum`

```
df[df.id.ne(2)].groupby(df.id.eq(2).cumsum()).size()
id
0    3
1    4
2    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: i am getting an error, the id isn't an object of the series. I think its because its an index

Comment: @CAIOWANDERLEYC then we just remove the id df[df.ne(2)].groupby(df.eq(2).cumsum()).size()

Comment: if i want do the same but with the ones that it's greater or equal 2. It's the same thing but for example, we have [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0], so i return this list [2, 5, 1]. I don't count the numbers equals or greater than 2

Comment: I already get it, its just change the func ne, eq to lt and gt

Answer (score 0):

Try `cumsum`, `groupby` and `count()`

Chained;

```
 df[df.id.ne(2)].groupby((df.id==2).cumsum())['id'].count().tolist()




 [3, 4, 1]
```

Comment: what is this df.id on assign func, it says that this object doesn't exist, the id on my series it's the index not a column

Comment: They all are working for me. I edited to remove the `df.assign`. `df.assign` is used to create a new column. In this case, I create a new column called group. I then use the column group to  `groupby` and  `count` the  `id`. The resulting count is sent to a list.

Comment: i think it's because id it isn't a column, still don't working

Comment: Me bad,  my problem.  That was stray text.  Removed it.  Please try now.